# Django - Update model object

Tags: python, django

I didn't find a simple answer to my case, so here I am.

Here is a simplification of my models:

```
class People(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    house = model.ForeignKey(House)
    salary = model.IntegerField()

class House(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key = True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My need is to update one person informations. For instance, let's say John has a big income and can afford painting his house in purple instead of yellow. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
 john = People.objects.get(identifier="john")
 john.salary = 10000
 john.house.color = "purple"
 john.house.save()
 john.save()
```

I would like to know what is the Django way to do something like that. Right now, I'm getting some errors like

```
john.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 546, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 650, in save_base
result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1661, in insert_query
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 937, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 56, in execute
six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 54, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "people_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (identifier)=("John") already exists.
```

and when I replace the save() with a save(force_update) I sometimes get a

```
DatabaseError: Forced update did not affect any rows.
```

I read something about the following method:

```
john = People.objects.filter(identifier="john").update(salary=10000)
```

but it's not really helping as I need also to update the foreign key and not only the People object.
What would you do?

Comment: "Some errors like..." is not at all helpful. What are the *exact* errors, and what does the traceback say? The code you have given is the correct way to do it, so the error is somewhere else.

Comment: edited with the traceback :)

Comment: This seems to be caused by your use of those charfields as a primary key. Is there any particular reason you've done that, rather than rely on Django's automatic ID field?

Comment: nope, I don't know why the former people working on this project did that. I'll change it to the django automatic way and I'll tell you if this works :)

Comment: I get a similar error, I know have: IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "people_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have occurred because you have manually/accidentally given a primary index to the 'identifier' field in your People table. If you are using phpmyadmin go to your table and make sure identifier isn't a primary key. You can remove the primary index by going to the relations view.

Comment: If I use the automatic Django way to have ids, I get the same error

Comment: Since you have set 'primary_key=True' to the identifier table, there is a conflict of values in the 'People' table. A single record in any django table will have a unique id (unless the tables are manually handled).. you may use this id to query your People table for unique entries instead of setting 'identifier' field as a 'primary key'