# Django - update fields inside django model object using kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-models

I searched for a simple answer to this question but couldn't really find any.
 [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138334/django-update-model-object) somewhat looks like it, but not quit the same so here it is.

Let's say I have a custom update method inside my Django model.

```
class People(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    house = model.ForeignKey(House)
    salary = model.IntegerField()

    def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
        # Here I want to do my update
        pass
```

What I want to do is use the `kwargs` to update my model.
Right now I am using the following:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    self.name = kwargs.get('name')
    self.house = kwargs.get('house')
    self.salary = kwargs.get('salary')
    self.save()
```

This is something that looks like what I really want to do:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    self.update(**kwargs)
```

`self.update` does not work for it raises an error:
`AttributeError: 'People' object has no attribute 'update'`

Also `self.objects.update` isn't possible due to the fact that the manager isn't accessible when using `self`.

My question now is, if this is possible and how this is done in Django.
It saves me a lot of time listing every attribute in my actual models.

Comment: What is the problem with `self.update`?

Comment: May `update_or_create` help?

Comment: @AmaroVita No, not really, because `update_or_create` also isn't a method of the model itself, but of the manager of the model. And the manager also isn't accessible by `self` so this doesn't work

Comment: @Nebulosar, may be, `self.__class__.objects.update_or_create()` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can iterate over the attributes, and update the values, then we call the `.save()` function:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
    self.save()
```

This will however set the attributes manually, so it is possible that there are some signals, triggers, etc. attached that will update and clean the values.

The `setattr(..)` is a Python function such that `setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z` (note that we pass `'y'` as a string in `setattr(..)`.

It is also impossible to update the attributes like `related_field__attribute`, etc.

Comment: Hi Willem, Thanks for answering my question, I've seen more of your answers on my questions and I appreciate that! Thank you. It's small and simple, just what I needed.

Comment: Indeed, Willem's name is everywhere :D Short and great answers as always! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that your current solution:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    self.name = kwargs.get('name')
    self.house = kwargs.get('house')
    self.salary = kwargs.get('salary')
    self.save()
```

is very brittle as it can possibly set any of name, house and salary to `None`.

A first clean solution would be to use a for loop and settattr:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, name, value)
    self.save()
```

but this is still brittle in that it doesn't check that the names passed are actually model field names. A safer implementation would use `self._meta.get_fields()` to check this:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    fieldnames = set(f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields())
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        if name not in fieldnames:
            raise ValueError("%s is not a field of %s" % (name, type(self).__name__))
        setattr(self, name, value)
    self.save()
```

and finally, you may want to avoid calling `save()` if nothing was updated, and only commit what was actually updated:

```
def my_fancy_update(self, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs:
        return

    fieldnames = set(f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields())
    updated = []
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        if name not in fieldnames:
            raise ValueError("%s is not a field of %s" % (name, type(self).__name__))
        setattr(self, name, value)
        updated.append(name)
    self.save(update_fields=updated)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if you should force the user to only pass valid kwargs by doing a `ValueError` but that is not really the question here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nebulosar as far as I'm concerned (as a developper), I'd rather have this `ValueError` so I know when I mistyped a field name or when some code has not been properly updated after a schema change, but YMMV...

Comment: I understand your argument, and market may vary indeed, so I want to explain my point of view in this situation: lets say when doing automatic imports of large XML files, you just want to import what works, The data itself is not relevant, the party delivering the data is responsible to make sure this is right. When importing I don't want to raise errors. At most the best thing to do in this case is LOGGING the error. So instead of brute exiting when some field is not right, you could also log it so you can see what was going wrong and still update the fields or something like that.

Comment: @Nebulosar user data (wherever it comes from) has to be sanitized / validated / eventually preprocessed before hitting the model anyway, so refusing unknown fields in the `update` method should not raise if the caller did his job. But once again, it's up to you...